# why type 2 FIR cannot be used to design high pass filter

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

Kindly explain why type 2 FIR filter cannot be used to design high pass filter.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9408/fir-filter-with-linear-phase-4-types/9413#9413), where the 4 types of linear phase FIR filters are compared.

Comment: please clarify how presence of a zero at Z=-1 prevent us from using type two FIR filter for designing HPF or BSF

Comment: $z=-1$ corresponds to the Nyquist (i.e. highest possible) frequency. If the filter's frequency response is zero at the highest frequency (and of course decays on the way there), you can't have a high pass or band stop filter, which are supposed to *pass* high frequencies.

Comment: How can you determine Z=-1 is the highest possible frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Type 2 filters are even and symmetric.  A signal with a frequency of $f_s/2$ is just a scaled version of `[+1,-1,+1,-1,+1,...]`.

That means, at $f_s/2$, the response of a type 2 filter will always be zero as the coefficients of the same magnitude are an even number of samples apart so they cancel each other out.

A filter with a magnitude frequency response of zero at $f_s/2$ makes a very poor high pass filter.