# Delay in Savitzky-Golay filtering

Tags: filters, python, delay, scipy, array-signal-processing

I am applying a Savitzky-Golay filter to a signal, using the scipy function.

I need to calculate the lag of the filtered signal, and how much is it behind the original signal.

Could someone shed some light on this matter? How could I calculate it with scipy? How should I interpret the result correctly?

I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 4):

Standard Savitzky-Golay filters are linear phase (type I) FIR filters. So they have an odd number of filter coefficients $2N+1$, and the delay equals $N$.

For a good overview of Savitzky-Golay filters see [this article](https://c.mql5.com/forextsd/forum/147/sgfilter.pdf) by Ronald Schafer.

For the definition of the four types of linear phase FIR filters see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9413/4298).

Comment: The delay is equals to N? The lenght of the data? I don't understand

Comment: No, $N$ as in $2N+1$ filter length. Signal length is arbitrary. This is another $N$ than the one in my answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks! In this way... My filter have 31 coefficients (just the windows lenght...), so it has a delay=15. Is it correct?

Comment: Why the result is so different than solving it as in the Max answer?

Comment: @SanRiente: As pointed out by Max, $2N+1$ is the (odd) filter length. If  you denote the odd filter length by $M$, the delay is $(M-1)/2$.

Comment: @SanRiente: The approach in Max's answer is a numerical one, finding the delay by correlating input and output signals. However, you know the delay directly from the filter length because it's a linear phase filter. So the result is the same, but it's easier to just determine the delay from the filter length, as I've explained in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for to be so heavy. Just to clarify: in my filter my window size is 31, so I have 31 coefficients, so delay = (31-1) / 2 = 15. Is it correct?

Comment: @SanRiente: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a cross correlation with 
`cc = scipy.signal.correlate(original,filtered)`

By position of the maximum, you can find out the filter delay. Just notice that the result will have length $2N-1$ with $N$ being the length of the original signal. So the delay in samples will be

`numpy.argmax(cc) -len(original)`

Comment: The both answers are very differents! I don't understand what to do!