# Equivalence between the linear phase of FIR filters and the (anti)symmetry of the coefficients

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, linear-phase

According to the Matt L.'s answer to [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61862/how-to-determine-if-fir-has-a-linear-phase-response-w-o-matlab/61870#61870) question, real-valued and causal FIR filters have a (generalized) linear phase response if and only if their coefficients satisfy (anti)symmetry condition. The proof of the reverse implication $\Leftarrow$ is straightforward and can be found in the literature but the proof of the forward implication doesn't seems easy. Indeed, [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01849361/file/FIR_filter.pdf) paper provides a proof but is there any easier way to prove that coefficients of a real-valued FIR filter with linear phase are either symmetric or antisymmetric?

Comment: Perhaps the material at the following web age will be of value to you: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/808.php

Comment: @RichardLyons Thanks for the helpful web page.